# Mongodb: which index to use for long url

Tags: mongodb

I understand that text index is good to index string of words, such as a paragraph.

however, is it also the best option for long string of one 'token' (can be 1000 chars or more)
such as url with lengthy query string?

(I need to search url that contains specific parameters in the query string. e.g. '&tag=123')

Comment: If you need to search for parameters then it would be a lot better to actually split up the url parts and store that in an array. You cannot "text search" on partial strings, and regular expressions on partial strings are not the most performant solution. Splitting up the content ( you know, just like we do in any API ) is basically the common sense option.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn. I thing you right. splitting url by & is very easy.